# print text between 2 pattern when find a match inside

Tags: sed, grep, match

for one of my script i need to print text between 2 pattern when a match if found inside, i dont find how to make it simple.

the content of the file is:

```
===== seble dom0 report =====
IP address: 10.42.0.100
location: slot-3.enclosure-43.eqx
ID: infra-dom0.dom0.seble
Xen-Version: 4.4
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v3 @ 2.60GHz

===== arnica dom0 report =====
IP address: 10.1.42.46
location: slot-3.enclosure-12.eqx
ID: infra-dom0.dom0-3
Xen-Version: 4.1
CPU: AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6174

===== sithtemd dom0 report =====
IP address: 10.1.42.191
location: slot-13.enclosure-7.vty
ID: infra-dom0.mutu119
Xen-Version: 4.4
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz
```

if i seach enclosure-7 for exemple i would like it return :

```
===== sithtemd dom0 report =====
IP address: 10.1.42.191
location: slot-13.enclosure-7.vty
ID: infra-dom0.mutu119
Xen-Version: 4.4
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz
```

It's a mix between a grep and a `sed -n "/===== /,/^$/p"` but can't find it...

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer:

```
perl -0777 -lne 'print for grep /enclosure-7/, /^=====.*?^$.*?\n/mgs' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`p` will be treated as a [regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html#Regexp)

```
awk -v p='enclosure-7' -v RS= '$0~p' file.dat
```

[Empty RS means that records are separated by one or more blank lines and nothing else.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/awk-split-records.html#awk-split-records)

Comment: Or just `awk -v RS= '/enclosure-7/' file.dat`. No need to complicate it with a variable. It's usually good to replicate the blank-line-separated format in the output though for the case where there's multiple matches: `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/enclosure-7/' file.dat`

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed '/^=====/{:a;N;/\n$/!ba;/enclosure-7/!d}' file
```